# Dynamically change environment variables in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy my app but I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically update the environment variables without rebuilding my app. I did some research and found out there are 3 possible ways

- Store configs inside a js file and update that with a script!
- Store configs in the server that loads the React app and access the
  variables via an endpoint
- Store configs in the window object, this is
  really strange!

Are these methods secure? What are the risks associated with these methods?

Any idea how Facebook, Airbnb or any other high volume websites update their configurations? I mean it would be pretty time consuming to rebuild the application every time right? Is it even a good idea to dynamically update my variables?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this!

Comment: Is this a static App?

Comment: well if you want to change server env vars (like node js process.env) from client app, the safest way would be to use some network request like http

Comment: @devserkan no, it is a dynamic App

Comment: @givehug so an example would be changing the URL of my backend. Right now what i would do is change the URL in .env file and deploy the App again but that would take up to 10 minutes to deploy. I want to know if there is any better ways to do it

Comment: How do you run your app on the server? If your app reads an environment variable then this means you are providing some via your running tool right?

Comment: @devserkan I will use a nodejs to run my code and in my react app I will just use process.env.Variable to access the env variables

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/i-built-this-now-what-how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-a-digitalocean-droplet-662de0fe3f48